# RVM use list[0]

Tags: ruby, rvm

Is there something like "RVM use 1" or "RVM use list[0]" instead of typing the entire version number. At any time , we see a list of may be 5 or more rubies and we can easily type a single digit number instead of X.X.X. This will help rvm gemset too.

Answer (score 4):

this will be possible in RVM 2.0 => https://docs.google.com/document/d/1xW9GeEpLOWPcddDg_hOPvK4oeLxJmU3Q5FiCNT7nTAc/edit?usp=sharing - anyone with the link can comment

Answer (score 4):

You could do something like this:

```
rubies=(`rvm list strings`)
rvm use ${rubies[1]}
```

rvm list strings - list installed rubies, machine passable form.
This is put into a bash array.

Comment: That works! I would love to vote up, but I don't have the 15 reps :|

Comment: please note that the index `1` is first element in ZSH and second in Bash - so you might want to change it to `${rubies[0]}` when in Bash

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by Shawns hack:

```
rvm use `rvm list strings | head -n 1`
```

Comment: I started down this path but didn't think it would work.    It ends up as rvm use v1 v2 v3.      It turns out the last argument wins so that this does work.

Comment: It is not possible `rvm list strings | wc -l` => `36` and `rvm list strings | head -n 1` => `ruby-1.9.3-p392-new` ... what version of rvm are you using? current one is `rvm version` => `rvm 1.20.3...`

Comment: Oh, I was using ``rvm use `rvm list strings| head -n 3 ` ` and was surprised that it worked for using the nth version.